# dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to send the property of my `InheritedWidget` to its child.

```dart
class Detector extends InheritedWidget {
  final bool isEditable;

  Detector({@required this.isEditable, @required Widget child, Key key})
      : super(child: child, key: key);

  static Detector of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Detector>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Detector oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.isEditable != isEditable;
  }
}
```

[I referred here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html). The widget is created by:

```dart
Detector(
  isEditable: otherObj.isEditable,
  child: command.makeWidget(context) // Extension method that returns new widget
);
```

And `makeWidget()` method calls the `of` method:

```dart
   final detector = Detector.of(context);
    if (detector != null && detector.isEditable) {
      return Container(
        child: ...,
      );
    }
```

always returns null.
Why does `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` return null? I use the extension method but give it the context from an ancestor widget.

Comment: Most common mistake passing the wrong context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the reasons you *shouldn't* use functions instead of classes to make reusable widgets. [What is the difference between functions and classes to create widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-widgets/53234826#53234826)

You are calling `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Detector>` on a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of `Detector`.

Instead of:

```dart
Detector(
  isEditable: otherObj.isEditable,
  child: command.makeWidget(context) // Extension method that returns new widget
);
```

refactor `command.makeWidget(context)` such that it's a `StatelessWidget` class instead of a function.

That will give you a `BuildContext` that is a descendant of `Detector` and will fix your issue.

Comment: Do you mean "one of the reasons you *should not* use functions"?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Ah.. Indeed haha

Comment: In linked question, I see a `BuildContext` cannot be used in functions. I replaced the extension method to `StatelessWidget`. Now the widget tree has widgets only for its children. It could be implemented without functions. Thank you.