# A non-null string must be provided to a text widget - Flutter Android

Tags: flutter, dart

My code was working fine but now I'm unable to see the Profile page as it generates an error and I'm unable to identify, even though I tried to return a Container() at the end of buildProfileButton() but it did not solve the issue as I updated the code of that function later on.

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String profileId;

  Profile({this.profileId});

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  final String currentUserId = currentUser?.id;
  bool isLoading = false;
  int postCount = 0;
  bool isFollowing = false;
  int followerCount = 0;
  int followingCount = 0;
  List<Post> posts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getProfilePosts();
    getFollowers();
    getFollowing();
    checkIfFollowing();
  }

  checkIfFollowing() async {
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await followersRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('userFollowers')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      isFollowing = doc.exists;
    });
  }

  getFollowers() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followersRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('userFollowers')
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      followerCount = snapshot.documents.length;
    });
  }

  getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      followingCount = snapshot.documents.length;
    });
  }

  getProfilePosts() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('userPosts')
        .orderBy('rating', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      postCount = snapshot.documents.length;
      posts = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    });
  }

  Column buildCountColumn(String label, int count) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          count.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 15.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  editProfile() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => EditProfile(currentUserId: currentUserId)));
  }

  Container buildButton({String text, Function function}) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: function,
        child: Container(
          width: 210.0,
          height: 27.0,
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color:
                  isFollowing ? Colors.white : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isFollowing ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildProfileButton() {
    bool isProfileOwner = currentUserId == widget.profileId;
    if (isProfileOwner) {
      return buildButton(
        text: "Edit Profile",
        function: editProfile,
      );
    } else if (isFollowing) {
      return buildButton(
        text: "Unfollow",
        function: handleUnfollowUser,
      );
    } else if (!isFollowing) {
      return buildButton(
        text: "Follow",
        function: handleFollowUser,
      );
    }
  }

  handleUnfollowUser() {
    setState(() {
      isFollowing = false;
    });
    followersRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('userFollowers')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });

    followingRef
        .document(currentUserId)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });

    activityFeedRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('feedItems')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });
  }

  handleFollowUser() {
    setState(() {
      isFollowing = true;
    });
    followersRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('userFollowers')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .setData({});

    followingRef
        .document(currentUserId)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .setData({});

    activityFeedRef
        .document(widget.profileId)
        .collection('feedItems')
        .document(currentUserId)
        .setData({
      "type": "follow",
      "ownerId": widget.profileId,
      "username": currentUser.username,
      "userId": currentUserId,
      "userProfileImg": currentUser.photoUrl,
      "timestamp": timestamp,
    });
  }

  buildProfileHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: usersRef.document(widget.profileId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            buildCountColumn("Videos", postCount),
                            buildCountColumn("Followers", followerCount),
                            buildCountColumn("Following", followingCount),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[buildProfileButton()],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.username,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.displayName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.bio,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  buildProfilePosts() {
    if (isLoading) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else if (posts.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/no_content.svg', height: 260.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "No Posts",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: posts,
    );
  }

  buildTogglePostOrientation() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.videocam,
              size: 30.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, titleText: "PROFILE"),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildProfileHeader(),
          Divider(),
          buildTogglePostOrientation(),
          Divider(
            height: 0.0,
          ),
          buildProfilePosts(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The debug console says that: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder

Comment: What line exactly gives you this error...You have a lot of Text widgets so knowing which Text widget is hard

Comment: Ther error says line 285 but after checking the code you dropped what is at line 285 isn't a Text probably because you didn't copy your imports

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi Line 285 is referencing a widget text.dart in flutter SDK itself. Not on project files.

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi Check this, it says line 237: https://prnt.sc/roprrp

Comment: Is it giving any line for the Text in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing `Text(description)`, write `Text(description ?? '')` so the Text widget will be empty if description is null.

When using the property of an object, instead of writing `Text(user.bio)` write `Text(user?.bio ?? '')` for the Text widget to get an empty string if `user` or `user.bio` is null.

You can Also make sure that the strings your using in the Text widget are never null.

Not related to the question but I see that you use a lot of functions to build your UI,
I suggest that you turn each of them to a separate widget to improve your app's performance. see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets) to learn more.

Comment: Even      `Text(downloadMessage?? '')`
shows this warning. `Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.`

Comment: This answer was written before the null-safety update. so if the variable is already not null, you don't need to use the `??` operator.