# Most elegant/efficient way to refactor widgets in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, refactoring

Searching online on "how to refactor Flutter widgets" I found that there exist two possible ways that are both functioning as per my testing, still very different from a structural standpoint. The second method, indeed includes and additional building instruction, which should bring a further burden on the app performances right?

This is the code I want to refactor:

```
Container(
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
            [long code to create a button with many properties],
            [long code to create a button with many properties],
            [long code to create a button with many properties],
            [long code to create a button with many properties],
        ],),);
```

These are the main ways I found:

1):

```
Widget MyButton(Color color, String text) {
    return [long code to create a button with many properties];
}
```

2):

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
    MyButton(this.color, this.text);

    final Color color;
    final String text;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return [long code to create a button with many properties];
    }
}
```

**Which is the best method?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look and consider this other question:

[What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets)

**Short answer**: It' better the second method (both efficient and elegant).

---

In the **first method (extract to a function)**, you are just creating a function that return the encapsulated widget.

In the **second method (extract to a class)**, you are extracting the widget to a new class that extends from `StatelessWidget`. This difference gives to the Flutter framework a way to make optimizations.