# Widget build or Function return?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm relatively new to coding with flutter and using widgets and I have a simple query. Here are 2 code snippets that have my themeData that I want to return to the `theme` property in my `MaterialApp`. The snippet is in a different file to the `main.dart` file and is imported in. Here's how it'll fit in.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'App Name',
    theme: AppTheme(),
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

Now my query is... 
Which is a better practice; Using a function to return a widget or creating another widget to parent that widget and return that?

```
ThemeData AppTheme(){
  return ThemeData(
    ...
  );
}
```

OR

```
class AppTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the better option is `class AppTheme extends StatelessWidget { ...` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234826/2252830

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! @pskink

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53234825/10003008. However, how can you return a `ThemeData` in the build method; it doesn't extend `Widget` afaik.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets)

Comment: @GregoryConrad Yeah, pskink already pointed that out. Thanks though!