# Flutter Extract Method vs. Extract Widget vs. Extract Flutter Widget in androidStudio

Tags: flutter, widget, refactoring, extract

Hi I'm new to Flutter and I have several questions regarding `Extract Method` and `Extract Widget` in Android Studio.

1. When it comes to making code clean and reusable,
   what is the difference between `Extract Method` and `Extract Widget`?
   When do I know what to use? It seems they both work fine to me.
2. If I `Right click` on a Widget that I want to extract and go to `Refactor` -> `Extract Flutter Widget` then it works, however if I `Left click` on a Widget to focus and use the hotkey `Command+Option+W`, it doesn't work. Why is it happening? Moreover if I go to `Flutter outline` -> select the Widget -> `Right click` -> `Extract Widget` then it shows the same result. What's the difference between `Extract Flutter Widget` and `Extract Widget`?

Thank you.

Comment: In this post they discuss the difference between Extract Method and Extract Widget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show a widget use the Extract widget and method is basically a function needs to be executed basically logical part.
You can do same by return the widget in methods but it's not a right choice as per performance basis.

But if you are a beginner then it's ohkk to use for now.

This comment is basically posted by Satyarth Mittal.

Comment: Returning widgets from methods is less performant than wrapping them in a widget class? can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

For testability and performance. use extract widget.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).