# Widgets in single file vs multiple files in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am wondering what is the best practice according to organization of widgets in Flutter. Let's image I am writing some bigger widget like side bar in the application. This widget consists of several smaller widgets (like title, some greeting, user data, list of menu buttons, etc.) that I know won't be reused in other widgets. And now my question is - should all of them be kept in the same file (widgets or methods that build these widgets) as their context is the same or maybe should I separate them into large amount of small files in order to write tests for them more easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a separate file shouldn't bring any testing-related advantages, as far as I know. Flutter unit tests are usually written in a separate directory anyway. Using a separate file for a widget is useful for **readability** and for **re-use** (as you mention) rather than for testing.

I personally try to have one public widget per file, and to break down complex widgets into smaller private classes ([not methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234826/3272066)) that reside in the same file. If a widget can be reused or if it's complex enough to make a file not readable, I declare it as a public class in a separate file.

Also: the more your codebase grows, the more you might find it useful to use directories (rather than files) to group together widgets that are used in the same "context".

Comment: I thought that it might be more useful from testing point of view since I can test all the widgets separately. As they are private, I cannot do this, I can only test them as a part of the main, public widget.

Comment: Ok. Then maybe I should express more explicitly what I meant: the main requirement for a class to be testable is to be public. It doesn't matter whether it is in its own file or in the file of a class that uses it, as long as the class you want to test is public.