# How to fill parent widget width in Flutter, but prevent stretching parent on all available space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There are two items in Column. Column must be "wrap content" (does not fill all available width). First item in column must fill space.

How to achieve this?
[image: screenshot]

My code now:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
      _item(context, '123456', '123456789000000'),
      _item(context, '1234567890000000', '1234567')
    ]));
  }

  Widget _item(BuildContext context, String firstLine, String secondLine) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.black12,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container( // This container's width must be not less than container below
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    child: Text(firstLine, style: theme.textTheme.headline4)),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                    child: Text(secondLine, style: theme.textTheme.headline4)),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to Column, then it cause stretching on all screen width instead just fit available width (see arrow on screenshot).

Comment: Instead of an `_item` Widget function, you should prefer a Widget class. Check this thread for the benefits of using Widget classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets

Comment: @Thierry in this case _item function will work absolutely in same way as separate stateless widget Item. In two cases item will rebuild when parent MyHomePage build called

Comment: For more complex or stateful elements separate widget really should be prefer

Answer (score 1):

After experiments with Flexible, LayoutBuilder, FittedBox I found this solution using IntrinsicWidth in combination with CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

```
IntrinsicWidth(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Container( // This container's width must be not less than container below
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      child: Text(firstLine, style: theme.textTheme.headline4)),
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.cyan,
                      child: Text(secondLine, style: theme.textTheme.headline4)),
                ]),
          )
```