# What's the best way to return widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There are two ways in my mind to `return` `widget` which is repeating again and again. lets see with the example for better understanding. if there is a `container` which is repeating multiple times with only `text` changing to if we apply `OOP` concepts we can refactor the code by extracting `container widget` and call it wherever we need but there are two ways (in my knowledge) to do this task both works fine but what would be the best practice?

```
Widget returnContainer(String text){
    return Container(....);
}
```

or creating stateless widget and return `container`

```
class ReturnContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  ReturnContainer(this.text);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(.....);
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53234825/12668727

Comment: really sorry I searched for this thing but as my mind didn't picked exact words to search

Comment: it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/53234825/10157127

Answer (score 1):

They're both valid solutions, but apply to different situations.
You would choose the return function if your widget needs to be called only in the dart file where you are implementing it.
You would otherwise choose a stateless widget if your code needs to be used many times in manu different files.