# Reusuable Stateless Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am creating reusable stateless widget for troubleshooting and maintenance. MyApp1 is a statelesswidget and am calling this widget MyApp1(title: 'title',) from a statefull widget.In order to segregate many lines of code and make troubleshooting simpler, another widgets firstone and Secondone are created. Here am passing a title data. I made two widgets firstone (widget function) and SecondOne (Statelesswidget). Although I am showing a text in both, the outcome differs.

```
class MyApp1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyApp1({super.key,required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
              Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
              firstone(context),
              SecondOne(title: 'title'),                        
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget firstone(context){
    return Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge);
  }

}

class SecondOne extends  StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const SecondOne({Key? key,required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge);
  }
}
```

Although the text styles are identical in both, my output is different. I don't have to supply the title data twice when using firstone (the widget function). Which is preferable: Stateless widgets or widget functions? If I use a stateless widget, I transmit data from a stateful widget to Myapp1 stateless widget and then to a second widget. Is this correct

My Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Classes should be preferred over functions that return widgets.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234826/6716211)

It's different because you're manually passing a `BuildContext` which is provided above the scope of where the default `ThemeData` can be accessed from (is provided by `MaterialApp`).

```dart
class MyApp1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyApp1({super.key,required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // <- this BuildContext is being used
   
    return MaterialApp( // <- this widget provides the `ThemeData`, which isn't accessible from the above context
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
              Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge), // <- refers to the `context` provided by build above
              firstone(context), // <- refers to the `context` provided by build above
              SecondOne(title: 'title'),                        
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget firstone(context){
    return Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge);
  }


class SecondOne extends  StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const SecondOne({Key? key,required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This uses the correct context, inherited from `MaterialApp` properly.
    return Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge);
  }
}
```

Comment: Classes should be preferred.  I transmit data from a stateful widget to Myapp1 stateless widget and then to a secondOne class StatelessWidget. Just consider am passing 10 data form stateful -> Myapp1 -> SecondOne. Does it affect memory?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not return `MaterialApp`  .
Direct return column in myapp1 class.
It will solve your issue

Comment: No it won't, this is the wrong answer. The issue is related to the `BuildContext` that is being used to lookup the `ThemeData` instance.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Which one is correct way firstone or SecondOne