# ERROR:The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like the program to transition a large screen and then also transition the screen with further list selections.
How can I remedy this error?

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
    ),
    Text(
      'Play画面',
    ),
    Text(
      'Make画面',
    ),
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[

        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.key),
          title: Text('設定1'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SetsFirst()));
          },
        ),
        Divider(),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.key),
          title: Text('設定2'),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SetsSecond()));
          },
        ),
        Divider(),
      ],
    )
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

[By preferring classes over functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets/53234826#53234826)

The issue is the `BuildContext` you're using for navigation.

Comment: How do I change the code to eliminate the error?

Comment: By doing as suggested and reading the detailed response which was linked:  preferring classes over functions. The issue is the `BuildContext` which is being passed to your static function.