# Performance difference between widget function and class

Tags: flutter, performance, widget, rebuild

What is the difference between both options in this case regarding rebuilding widgets and performance aspects?

Widget class:

```
class Dummy() extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dummy();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text(„text“);
  }
}
```

Option 1:

```
class Option1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Option1();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: const Dummy(),
    );
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
class Option2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Option2();

  Widget createDummyWidget() {
    return const Dummy();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: createDummyWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In general, factoring out a widget is preferred over factoring out a helper method because the widget might not need rebuilding even when the parent widget is rebuilt.

Comment: This has been answered thoroughly before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets/53234826#53234826

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it did not answer my question since they are talking about built-in widgets. Here, we are working with a widget we defined that is either directly inserted or returned by a function. In this case, returning a widget is fine, isn‘t it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Splitting widgets to methods is an antipattern

So, for example, if we have a widget that looks something like this:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('Counter: $_counter'),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Hello'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('there'),
                  Text('world!'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

if use function widget

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  Widget _buildNonsenseWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Hello'),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('there'),
              Text('world!'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('Counter: $_counter'),

        // The deeply nesting widget is now refactored into a
        // separate method and we have a cleaner build method. Yay!
        _buildNonsenseWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**So what’s the problem, really?**

Whenever the value of _counter changes, the framework calls the build method. This triggers our widget to rebuild itself. The problem is that _buildNonsenseWidget() gets called every time the value of _counter changes - which ends up rebuilding the widget tree over and over again.
Rebuilding for nothing
In this case, there’s no reason to rebuild that particular widget tree.

The widget tree returned by _buildNonsenseWidget() is stateless by nature - we only need to build it once. Sadly, because the widget tree is built by the _buildNonsenseWidget() method, the Flutter framework rebuilds it every time when the parent widget rebuilds.

Essentially, we’re wasting precious CPU cycles in rebuilding something that doesn’t need to be rebuilt. This happens because from the framework’s perspective, there’s no difference between a long-ass build method and a build method split into multiple smaller methods. Mind you, this is only a simple example - this has a more significant impact on more complex apps.

Splitting long build methods - revisited
The solution for this one is relatively simple, although it results in a couple of extra lines of code. Instead of splitting build methods into smaller methods, we split them into widgets - StatelessWidgets, that is.

When we refactor the previous example, we’ll end up with this:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('Counter: $_counter'),

        // The deeply nesting widget is now refactored into a
        // stateless const widget. No more needless rebuilding!
        const _NonsenseWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _NonsenseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _NonsenseWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Hello'),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('there'),
              Text('world!'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Conclusion**

Instead of splitting you build methods into multiple smaller methods, split them into StatelessWidgets. This way, you won’t be rebuilding your static widget trees multiple times for nothing but wasted CPU cycles. When it comes to optimizing performance of Flutter apps, this is probably one of the lowest hanging fruits.

I used this article : https://iiro.dev/splitting-widgets-to-methods-performance-antipattern/

Answer (score 1):

I call the target widget (TestWidget1) through inline vs function, then put the print() at TestWidget1 build() method, check the log, and it's the same (call TestWidget1 through function won't cause rebuild)

So what is the difference in this case? I think it is just about we need a little bit more memory (since we create a function), **not about the rebuild**

[image]

Also tested **without const** when calling TestWidget1, or changing TestWidget1 to stateful, print log is also the same for both ways

So every setState -> function recall -> **not mean target widget rebuild**