# Performance declaring widget in stateful widget's build

Tags: flutter, performance, widget, rebuild

I saw this post on stack overflow

[Performance difference between widget function and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294818/performance-difference-between-widget-function-and-class)

Where

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  Widget _buildNonsenseWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Hello'),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('there'),
              Text('world!'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('Counter: $_counter'),

        // The deeply nesting widget is now refactored into a
        // separate method and we have a cleaner build method. Yay!
        _buildNonsenseWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Has an impact on performance because it can cause unneeded rebuilds. But I was wondering if I have

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dummy = DummyWidget();

    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('Counter: $_counter'),
        dummy,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Would that have the same negative impact on performance (having those unneeded rebuilds)? Or would it be just a performant as

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text('Counter: $_counter'),
        DummyWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: on case 2 & 3 will be same, declaring inside build method doesn't make any difference & if the `DummyWidget` contains some expensive builds/animation 2 and 3 will provide better performance being context separation AFAIK.

Comment: In general, *your* code should never attempt to cache anything that uses a context between builds (including building subwidgets).  Imagine that context changes every time, and you'll get the proper model.  The framework already heavily optimizes the reuse of existing built widgets *when it can*.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz could you give an example? I'm not sure what you mean with the sub widget caching part. Am I doing that in the examples I gave?

Comment: The second and third item are likely identical, unless the third one had a Builder boundary somewhere.