# What is the best way to define/store when I have a lot of TextFormField widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, mobile-development, textformfield

I have 20 input fields in my app. What is the best way to define `TextFormField` widgets?

For example:

```
Column(
          children: [
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
            _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController),
          ],
        ),
```

Should I have 20 separate methods? Is it the correct way to define? Or what should I do? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Avoid using helper methods altogether and instead define and use own defined classes/widgets.

For reference:

https://youtu.be/IOyq-eTRhvo

And another SO question where it has been answered:

[What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have 20 different methods. You should use `ListView.builder` code like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _buildCariUnvanTextField(unvanController);
  },
),
```

If the widgets are different, I think the only way is to have 20 different methods.

Comment: It's totally my fault that you don't understand the question. Each TextFormField is representing another field. I've duplicated the same widget just as an example.

Comment: Hi @AlicanKesen, if the widgets are not the same, I think the only way is to have 20 different methods

Comment: I think too. I just wondered is there another way. Thank you