# Flutter: What is good practice for making the custom widget?

Tags: flutter

I am confused about good practice between creating the custom widget with the `Widget` function and the `class` (stf,stl).

**For the example about creating the custom widget with the `Widget` function:**

```
class FieldCustomWidget {
  static Widget textField(...) {
    return ...;
  }

  static Widget idCardNumberField(...) {
    return ...;
  }

  static Widget phoneField(...) {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

**For the example about creating the custom widget with the `class` (stf,stl):**

```
class TextFieldCustomWidget  extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  const TextFieldCustomWidget ({Key? key, ...}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

```
class IdCardNumberFieldCustomWidget  extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  const IdCardNumberFieldCustomWidget ({Key? key, ...}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

```
class PhoneFieldCustomWidget  extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  const PhoneFieldCustomWidget ({Key? key, ...}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

All customer widgets can use the `Widget` function or `stl` because I am using [state management](https://pub.dev/packages/get).
What is good practice?
If you have another way, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general convention don't use functions to create widgets. Here is a discussion if you want to know more details about this.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19269

[What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets/53234826#53234826)

If you are following a functional programming paradigm you can use the [functional_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/functional_widget) package.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful link. My question looks duplicated from these questions.