# Compile time const methods in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to create compile-time methods in Dart/Flutter? I want to create a helper method to return DataTable headers. The old code looks as follows:

```dart
DataTable(
  columns: const [
    DataColumn(label: Row(children: [Icon(Icons.foo1), Text('Bar 1')])),
    DataColumn(label: Row(children: [Icon(Icons.foo2), Text('Bar 2')])),
    DataColumn(label: Row(children: [Icon(Icons.foo3), Text('Bar 3')])),
    DataColumn(label: Row(children: [Icon(Icons.foo4), Text('Bar 4')])),
  ],
  // ...
```

To make the code more readable and uniform, I created a helper method:

```dart
static Row _generateTableHeader(IconData icon, String text) {
  return Row(children: [Icon(icon), Text(text)],);
}
```

I now lost the ability to declare the columns array as `const`. Is there a way to declare the `_generateTableHeader` method as a compile-time method so that I can still use the constant declaration of the coluns array and still profit from that performance boost?

Or should I create a `StatelessWidget` instead? Or a class inheriting from `Row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create a `StatelessWidget` instead. This way, you can take advantage of using the `const` constructor, and the widget is now reusable. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234826/13625293) to learn more about why classes are preferred over functions to make reusable widget-tree.

```dart
class TableHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableHeader(this.icon, this.text, {super.key});

  final IconData icon;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [Icon(icon), Text(text)],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I even tried to outsource the `DataColumn` generation, but unfortunately that doesn't inherit from `Widget`. Would it make sense to do that?

Comment: You could probably make a list of [Records](https://dart.dev/language/records) and use the `.map` method that return a `DataColumn` filled with information from the Record, but I don't think for this case is necessary (might be handy for large data, or if you previously had a list of objects from a custom model)

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there a way to create compile-time methods in Dart/Flutter?
A: No, but a reference to static method (closure) can be used as a constant value.

Q: Is there a way to create methods that return compile-time constant value?
A: No. Outside the method, value will not be considered `const` and cannot be used as a constant in assignment expressions.

Q: Is there a way to create compile-time constant values inside a method body from arguments passed as constant values?
A: No. There is no way to declare this in the method parameter declaration.