# Is this correct way to use Classes and Functions-Methods in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am learning flutter, I am newbie, I was wondering is this correct way to use methods with classes?
I am trying to understand the structure, the easiest and simple way.
Is it okay to return style widgets with methods like this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenDemo1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenDemo1({super.key});
  final String mainText1 = "Welcome";
  final String subText1 = "Lorem ipsum dollar sit amet";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          MainTextStyle(mainText1: mainText1),
          SubTextStyle(subText1: subText1),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubTextStyle extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubTextStyle({
    super.key,
    required this.subText1,
  });

  final String subText1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      subText1,
      style: SubTextStyleWithGreen(),
    );
  }

  TextStyle SubTextStyleWithGreen() {
    return TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        color: Colors.green,
        letterSpacing: 1,
        fontSize: 16);
  }
}

class MainTextStyle extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainTextStyle({
    super.key,
    required this.mainText1,
  });

  final String mainText1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      mainText1,
      style: MainTextStyleWithYellow(),
    );
  }

  TextStyle MainTextStyleWithYellow() {
    return TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        letterSpacing: 1,
        fontSize: 42);
  }
}
```

I am trying to understand the structure, the easiest and simple way. I created method for classes, I am not sure if this is easy and correct way.

Comment: Use own widget classes instead of custom functions, see this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets/53234826#53234826

Comment: As far as i understand from the link using classes is better no need to split the code with methods-functions

Comment: I would prefer creating const variable for this case