# How to create a button in a filled TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

It's probably easy to understand if you look at it from the bottom.

```flutter
final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

PreferredSizeWidget _appBar() {
  final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  return AppBar(
    flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: deviceSize.width / 10 * 8,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xFFf4f4f4),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      // filled: true,
                      // fillColor: Colors.blue,
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'hintText',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF888888),
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, bottom: 6),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                if (_textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty)
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _textEditingController.clear();
                      });
                    },
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/delete.png'),
                  ),
                // . . . (Add any remaining widgets here)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

When there is text in the text field, this code should create `ElevatedButton`, but that doesn't happen.

What can I do to make the button appear?

Comment: Listen to the controller and when it changes to or from empty call `setState` so that `build` gets called and can redraw with[out] the button. see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/addListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty` part is only "read" when the `_appBar()` method is called, so probably in your widget's `build` method. This app bar doesn't know it should rebuild when the text controller value changes. You have a few options to choose from on how to solve it, two of them, among others are as follows:

- Wrap your `InkWell` with the `if` in [`ListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListenableBuilder-class.html). The `TextEditingController` is a `ChangeNotifier`, which is a `Listenable`. Something that you can listen to. It "fires" when the controller's value changes.

  ```dart
  ListenableBuilder(
    listenable: _textEditingController,
    builder: (context, child) =>
      _textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty ? child! : const SizedBox(),
    child: InkWell(), // Your button
  )
  ```

  If the text is empty I'm returning a `const SizedBox()`, which is basically a widget with no size and contents, because I need to return *something* in the `builder`.
- In the `initState()` of your `StatefulWidget` `addListener` on the `_textEditingController` and in its callback, call `setState()` whenever the value of the controller changes. This will rebuild this stateful widget on every controller change, so the condition in the `if` will be read again and the button will appear when necessary.

---

Also, looking at your code example, I see one issue and one thing you may not be aware of.

- Calling `setState` is only necessary when you want your widget to be rebuilt. Text editing controller methods don't need to be called inside a `setState`, because you pass this controller to a text field that listens on its changes. You'd need this `setState` only if you wanted to rebuild your stateful widget.
- Make sure to read this Q&A: [What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a variable after `_textEditingController`:

```dart
bool isTextFieldEmpty = false;
```

Then do this in `TextField`:

```flutter
onChanged: (value) {
    value.isEmpty
        ? isTextFieldEmpty = false
        : isTextFieldEmpty = true;
    setState(() {});
}
```

Then do this where you want to put your `Buttton`:

```flutter
isTextFieldEmpty
    ? ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
    //do someThing
}, child: Text('Press'))
     : Container();
```