# Flutter Checkbox Not Getting Checked/Unchecked Immediately

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I have a list of checkboxes as shown in the image below. However, when I click the checkbox to check/uncheck, nothing happens. I have to click the apply button, then reopen the filter modal for it to update. Can anyone help me to find out why it wont update immediately after I press the checkbox? any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Source Code:

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DashboardPage> createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonData = [];
  List<bool> selectedItems = [];
  bool checkVal = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadJsonData();
    initializeSelectedItems();
  }

  void initializeSelectedItems() {
  // Only initialize selectedItems if it's empty
    if (selectedItems.isEmpty) {
      selectedItems = List<bool>.generate(jsonData.length, (index) => false);
    }
  }


  void loadJsonData() {
    // Replace this with your actual JSON data loading logic
    jsonData = [
      {
        "name": "K1",
        "totalSST": 54,
        "sstInService": 52,
        "sstOutOfService": 2,
        "cashLevelNormal": 48,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 6,
      },
      {
        "name": "K2",
        "totalSST": 46,
        "sstInService": 42,
        "sstOutOfService": 4,
        "cashLevelNormal": 45,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 1,
      },
      {
        "name": "K3",
        "totalSST": 34,
        "sstInService": 32,
        "sstOutOfService": 2,
        "cashLevelNormal": 30,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 4,
      },
      {
        "name": "K4",
        "totalSST": 48,
        "sstInService": 45,
        "sstOutOfService": 3,
        "cashLevelNormal": 46,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 2,
      },
      {
        "name": "K5",
        "totalSST": 36,
        "sstInService": 32,
        "sstOutOfService": 4,
        "cashLevelNormal": 30,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 6,
      },
      {
        "name": "K6",
        "totalSST": 58,
        "sstInService": 54,
        "sstOutOfService": 4,
        "cashLevelNormal": 56,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 2,
      },
      {
        "name": "K7",
        "totalSST": 24,
        "sstInService": 24,
        "sstOutOfService": 0,
        "cashLevelNormal": 22,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 2,
      },
      {
        "name": "K8",
        "totalSST": 64,
        "sstInService": 63,
        "sstOutOfService": 1,
        "cashLevelNormal": 58,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 6,
      },
      {
        "name": "K9",
        "totalSST": 50,
        "sstInService": 45,
        "sstOutOfService": 5,
        "cashLevelNormal": 49,
        "lowCashOutOfCash": 1,
      },
    ];
    initializeSelectedItems();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF6F9FE),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  // Dashboard Container
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 26.0, right: 26.0, bottom: 15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Dashboard",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 28.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Hello, Danish Ghazi!",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color: Color(0xFF949494),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "HQ Executive",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color: Color(0xFF949494),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                                  child: Image(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/Profile_Picture.png'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                    vertical: 5,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        25,
                      ),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                        width: 1.0,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.white,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          25,
                        ),
                        color: Color(0xFF3CADD9),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Color(0xFF2D8EB4),
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      tabs: const [
                        Tab(
                          text: 'List View',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Summary View',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //List View Content
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
                      child: RefreshIndicator(
                        onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [

                              //Search Input
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    suffixIcon: Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Color(0xFFADADAD)),
                                    ),
                                    hintText: 'Search Keyword',
                                    hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                                        width: 2.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                                        width: 2.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),

                              //Filter Button
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                  child: TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // Validate and handle the button press
                                      showModalBottomSheet(
                                        context: context,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                          return buildFilterPopupContent();
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                                      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF6F9FE), // Set the background color
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), // Set the border radius
                                        side: BorderSide(
                                          color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF), // Set the border color
                                          width: 2.0, // Set the border width
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 6.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.filter_alt_rounded,
                                            color: Colors.black, // Set the color of the icon
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(width: 2.0), // Add some spacing between the icon and text
                                          Text(
                                            'Filter',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontSize: 16.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                                child: buildListViewContent(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    buildSummaryViewContent(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildListViewContent() {
    return Column(
      children: jsonData.map((data) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              side: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                width: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.black,
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                  primary: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              child: ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(
                  data['name'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                children: [

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 10.0),
                    child: const Divider(
                      color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                      thickness: 1.5,
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ),

                  for (var key in ['totalSST', 'sstInService', 'sstOutOfService', 'cashLevelNormal', 'lowCashOutOfCash'])
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                          child: buildTotalNumberContainer(
                            title: key,
                            value: data[key],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3CADD9),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Detailed View',
                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );

  }

  Widget buildTotalNumberContainer({required String title, required int value}) {

    Color containerColor;

    switch (title) {
      case 'sstInService':
        containerColor = Color(0xFF6EA4F4);
        break;
      case 'sstOutOfService':
        containerColor = Color(0xFFF46E6E);
        break;
      case 'cashLevelNormal':
        containerColor = Color(0xFF6EA4F4);
        break;
      case 'lowCashOutOfCash':
        containerColor = Color(0xFFF46E6E);
        break;
      default:
        containerColor = Color(0xFFB0B0B0); // Default color
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: containerColor.withOpacity(0.6),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  getTitleForTotalNumberContainer(title),
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 80.0,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFF3F3F3).withOpacity(0.75),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
                      width: 1.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      value.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String getTitleForTotalNumberContainer(String title) {
    switch (title) {
      case 'totalSST':
        return 'Total SST';
      case 'sstInService':
        return 'SST In-Service';
      case 'sstOutOfService':
        return 'SST Out-of-Service';
      case 'cashLevelNormal':
        return 'Cash Level Normal';
      case 'lowCashOutOfCash':
        return 'Low Cash / Out of Cash';
      default:
        return title;
    }
  }



  buildSummaryViewContent() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Text('Summary View'),
      ),
    );
  }


  Future<void> _handleRefresh() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // Simulating a delay

    setState(() {
      loadJsonData(); // Replace this with your actual refresh logic
    });
  }

  Widget buildFilterPopupContent() {
    initializeSelectedItems();
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Filter By Region',
                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _resetCheckboxes();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Reset',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Color(0xFF3CADD9),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // Add a separator between the checkboxes and buttons
          const Divider(height: 10, thickness: 1.0, color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF)),

          // Wrap the jsonData names in a scrollable ListView with checkboxes
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: jsonData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Checkbox(
                      value: selectedItems[index],
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedItems[index] = value!;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      jsonData[index]['name'],
                      style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      // Handle tap on the name if needed
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // Add a separator between the checkboxes and buttons
          const Divider(height: 10, thickness: 1.0, color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF)),

          // Button Section
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Handle cancel button press
                      Navigator.pop(context); // Close the popup
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Cancel',
                      style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Handle filter button press
                      // You can use the selectedItems list to get the selected items
                      // For example, you can print the selected names:
                      for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
                        if (selectedItems[i]) {
                          print('Selected: ${jsonData[i]['name']}');
                        }
                      }
                      initializeSelectedItems(); // Initialize the selectedItems list
                      Navigator.pop(context); // Close the popup
                      setState(() {}); // Trigger a rebuild to update the UI
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Apply',
                      style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _resetCheckboxes() {
    setState(() {
      selectedItems = List<bool>.generate(jsonData.length, (index) => false);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: wrap  the content in your`buildFilterPopupContent` with `StatefullBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal widget that is being called inside the builder of this `showModalBottomSheet`:

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return buildFilterPopupContent();
  },
);
```

is not reactive to the state of `DashboardPage`. To make it works as expected, I suggest to move the state and all of its logic to a new stateful widget:

```dart
class FilterPopupContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterPopupContent({super.key});

  @override
  State<FilterPopupContent> createState() => _FilterPopupContentState();
}

class _FilterPopupContentState extends State<FilterPopupContent> {
  // Put the states that was previously inside _DashboardPageState here (including all its logic)
  List<bool> selectedItems = [];
  // and other states that is needed by this popup content

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Put the code that was previously inside buildFilterPopupContent method here
  }
}
```

and then show the bottom sheet like this:

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return FilterPopupContent();
  },
);
```

---

Also some other thing worth to read:

[What is the difference between functions and classes to create reusable widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234825/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-classes-to-create-reusable-widgets)